# how write with xlsxwriter in excel in a existing file without deleting the old data

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

i know my question is quite strange but i have a problem,

When i try to put "toto" at line a5, it suppress all my old data.
there is my code (i just followed the documentation).

```
import xlsxwriter
 
# Workbook() takes one, non-optional, argument
# which is the filename that we want to create.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
 
# The workbook object is then used to add new
# worksheet via the add_worksheet() method.
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
 
# Use the worksheet object to write
# data via the write() method.
worksheet.write('A4', 'Hello..')
worksheet.write('B1', 'Geeks')
worksheet.write('C1', 'For')
worksheet.write('D1', 'Geeks')
 
# Finally, close the Excel file
# via the close() method.
workbook.close()
```

that code functions, but i would like to add some elements after this.
When i retry the function with differents values, it deletes the hello on a4 etc
how can i do?
Thanks for yours answer,

Comment: do you want to update the data?? or always add a new worksheet?

Comment: i want to update the data. Robxon a user said me its impossible, i have to use openpyxl

Comment: ty for your comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XlsxWriter can only create new files. It cannot read or modify existing files.
There is a module called [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that allows you to read and write to preexisting excel files.